# $\mathfrak{A}\vDash\alpha$ iff $\mathfrak{A}\vDash\forall v_i\alpha$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Let $\mathfrak{A}$ a $\rho-$structure, $\alpha\in Formula_\rho$ and $v_i\in VAR$. Prove that $\mathfrak{A}\vDash\alpha$ iff $\mathfrak{A}\vDash\forall v_i\alpha$.

I proved that if $\mathfrak{A}\vDash\alpha$, then $\mathfrak{A}\vDash\forall v_i\alpha$: if $a\in A$, then $\mathfrak{A}\vDash\alpha[s(v_n/a)]$ because $\mathfrak{A}\vDash\alpha[s]$ for all $s\in^\omega A$ and, in particular, $\mathfrak\vDash\alpha[s(v_n,a)]$.

I'm stuck on the other implication. Any hint, please?

Comment: But $\mathfrak A \vDash \forall v_i \alpha$ means that $\mathfrak A \vDash (\forall v_i \alpha)[s]$ for every $s$ and this in turn is $\mathfrak A \vDash \alpha[s(v_i/a)]$ for every $a \in A$.

Comment: Yeah, but i'm stuck in how to deduce that this implies that $A\vDash \alpha[s]$ because I have that $A\vDash\alpha[s(v_n/a)]$ for all $a \in A$ not what I need

Comment: You have to use the fact that what matters in the satisfaction relation are only the value that $s$ assigns to free variables. You can prove by induction that if $y$ is not free in $\alpha$ then $\vDash \alpha[s]$ iff $\vDash \alpha [s']$ if $s$ and $s'$ are equal except for values for $y$.